# Tell selenium to look in my C:/Downloads folder (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

me again!!

I have a question based around the download of a file.  I was helped with setting up a Firefox profile to set a download to save a file directly without a pop up window.  Now I need to tell Selenium to confirm that the said downloaded file is in my downloads folder on C drive to complete the test.  Is there a way to do this? I've trawled for answers and have gotten nothing.

I first tried by setting a path like so on my env.rb file but didn't get very far with it:

```
$download_location = 'C:/Users/User/Downloads'
def download_location(path)
   $download_location + path
end
```

Then telling cucumber to visit this location and confirm the name of the file.

Any help on pointing selenium to the location and confirming the name of a csv file would be hugely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You wouldn't need `selenium` to do this, you'd need a `ruby` based file manager library. I would imagine there's an inbuilt library within `ruby` that could do so.

Comment: There is a gem called filetest, I could use a command requiring that gem?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with `ruby` but it does sound promising. All you'd need to do is check if the file exists in a directory after all.

Comment: FWIW: `FileTest` isn't a gem; it's a ruby module.  From [rdoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/FileTest.html): `It exists as a standalone module, and its methods are also insinuated into the File class.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use ruby instead of selenium, you can use the [`exists?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-exist-3F) method to check the downloads directory for a given file, and it will return a Boolean result.  For example:

```
File.exists?('C:\Users\User\Downloads\foo.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that worked for me:

```
puts Dir["C:/Users/OSAT TESTING/Downloads/**/fleet_#{export}_export_all_*.csv"]
```

This confirmed the download of the file by looking in my downloads folder and returning the file path + name of any file that contained "fleet_#{export}_export_all_*.csv" in cmd prompt.

Thank you all for your help

:-)